# Application bar icon text length

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am currently coding a Windows phone application. The application will have an application bar with three icons. The name of the first icon are "Karta" the name of the second icon are "Frågor" and the name of the third icon are "Inställningar" (the names are in Swedish).

Now to my problem, the application does not include the full name of "Inställningar", I've read around a lot on the internet and this information came up alot:

"Avoid Using Menu Item text: That is too long as the text Will run off the screen. The recommended maximum length is between 14 and 20 characters."

But my text is only 13 characters (or is this even to icon bar?), can anyone help me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Application Bar menu items are separate from the Application bar buttons. The menu items show up when you press the "..." and are in vertical list form. The application bar buttons are what is always visible with their descriptive text shown when a user presses the "..."

For Application bar buttons, it looks like the maximum text length is 11 characters before it starts cutting off. Unfortunately there is not any way to change this. You'll either have to shorten it or add the item to the menu instead of the button part of the application bar.

Comment: Thank you for your answear. Think it's pretty bad that you can not have more letters when there is room for many more.