# How to change text width on a AppBarButton in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, width, textblock, appbar

[image: Example]

I don't want this single letter 'e' to break to the next line. Instead, I want a single word.

Does anyone have an idea how to accomplish this?

Comment: It's not possible. 

More info: [Application bar icon text length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415801/application-bar-icon-text-length)

Comment: oh, right. thanks, man. could you answer the question? with this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to change the max. length (**11** characters) of the `ApplicationBarIconButton` description text.

More information: [Application bar icon text length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415801/application-bar-icon-text-length).